# vectorize data from struct in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have created a struct by:

```
a(1).x = {[1.1 5 8], [3 5 6]};
a(2).x = {[3.1 0 4], [9 8 7]};
```

and wish to obtain an array with value [1.1 3.1].

I have tried:

```
a.x{1}(1,1)
Field reference for multiple structure elements that is
followed by more reference blocks is an error.
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Do you want a one-liner?

Comment: I wish to avoid for loops, a couple of lines would be acceptable.

Comment: I am not sure if I got it right. What must be the expected output for the given input?

Comment: I gotta ask you though - Why not use numeric arrays if you have such uniformly structured data? And by `structured`, I don't mean the `structure` you have it there though. So, you can think about using 3D or even 2D (if you get your indexing right) numeric arrays.

Comment: So, in the end you didn't like *anyone's* idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax error tells that you cannot further sub-reference inside multiple struct elements. So, the obvious one-liner—much slower than a `for` loop—that saves memory would be:

```
arrayfun(@(y) y.x{1}(1), a)
```

Just for you to compare performance, the loop-based version

```
function A = my_extractor(S)

        A = zeros(size(S));
        N = numel(S);

        for k = 1:N
                A(k) = S(k).x{1}(1);
        end;

end
```

Comment: +1 This is how I would to it too. In fact, I had answered the same, not having seen this

Answer (score 1):

If your `.x` field will always have the same dimensions then you could try

```
A = vertcat(a.x);
X = vertcat(A{:,1});
X(:,1)
```

Comment: but I am dealing with a relatively large array, using vertcat is not quite practical.

Comment: @ChenmingZhang because it's slow or because the fields can have different numbers of elements from one another?

Comment: I have modified the question more accurately to describe the data struct. the sub arrays are in thousands. sorry for the update

Comment: @ChenmingZhang what about two calls to `vertcat`?